# Use array or separate tables in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm confused to find the best solution

I have a form which accepts input of flight plans and each plan may have some details and one or many (up to 30) date.

Form insert info into a SQL Server table.

The problem: I need to have 2 type of output from table:

1. get the info of all flight in a certain date
2. get info of a certain plan and reload the form with the information of that plan with all dates (in case of edit)

When I think about #1 issue it seems two tables (one table store dates, another for plan detail) is better.

And when I think about #2 issue, it seems better to have one table with a column that stores array of plans date (each day as int) and load the form.

How can I design my database that can do both (optimal) , in my project (is there another way?)

---

**PS**:    i have more problem with issue #2 users usually search flights by callsign and it return many flight id , and user choose one to see details in form, so by two table i need to have two loop query(first find a flight id in table1 and then find dates in table2 for that flight ID and continue to find another flight ID and ...) it make program so Slow,

now in know that use of array is completly wrong, but to reduce need of loop query, what if i make the table much bigger (now have 16 column, add 30 column for each possible date)

Comment: I'm as confused as you are.  I'll just say that one table with an array column is basically two tables so do yourself a favor and go with the two tables solution.

Comment: array column will be difficult to update and won't allow any indexing. This technique should be used only when the performance gain is critical, editing complexity can be handled and no one is querying this column.

Comment: So if its not possible to use array what should I do, for issue #1

Comment: You should ***never ever*** put more than one value into a database cell. It violates **first normal form** of database design and will cause you endless grief down the line. The concept for storing *multiple values* in a relational database **is a TABLE** - so use that!

Comment: table #1 for plan details, table #2 with pairs of date&planid.  table #2 can have index on each column to allow both queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a 2 table approach.  I've modeled some options in this SQL Fiddle. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5210f/5

Basically you store the flight data in one table and the flight dates in another. Then you use joins or 2 queries to fill out your form.

**Issue 1**
This query will find all flights based on the 2 table approach that are scheduled on September 1st.

```
select * 
from FlightPlan fp
join FlightDate fd
  on fp.FlightId = fd.FlightId
where FlightDate between '2016-09-01' and '2016-09-02'
order by fp.FlightId, FlightDate;
```

**Issue 2**
This query will return all flight data for a single flight id 1.  You'll get the flight data multiple tiles but this can be dealt with.  The flight id will be the same on all rows so read the first record to fill out your base flight info, then each subsequent record line to fill in the dates.

```
select * 
from FlightPlan fp
join FlightDate fd
  on fp.FlightId = fd.FlightId
where fp.FlightId = 1
order by fd.FlightDate asc;
```

**Issue 2 - alternative**
Alternately you can take the 2 query approach. 
First, load the base flight data from the flight data table.

```
select * from FlightPlan fp where fp.FlightId = 1;
```

Then load the flight dates from the flight date table

```
select * from FlightDate fd where fd.FlightId = 1 order by FlightDate asc;
```

I've used both approaches to Issue 2.  The first option allows a single query to fetch all of the data you'll need. If the FlightData table has a lot of updates run against it I'd use the alternative option to avoid locks.   The alternative is also arguably simpler to read and understand but ends up being more C# code to write.

In case the SQL Fiddle stops working altogether, here is the full sql script.

```
create table FlightPlan(
  FlightId int primary key, 
  Name varchar( 80 ) not null
);

create table FlightDate (  
  FlightDate datetime, 
  FlightId int references FlightPlan( FlightId )
);


insert into FlightPlan ( Name, FlightId ) values ( 'Phoenix to Reno', 1 );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 1, '2016-09-01 10:30:00' );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 1, '2016-10-01 10:30:00' );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 1, '2016-11-01 10:30:00' );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 1, '2016-12-01 10:30:00' );

insert into FlightPlan ( Name, FlightId ) values ( 'Reno to Phoenix', 2 );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 2, '2016-09-01 23:30:00' );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 2, '2016-10-01 23:30:00' );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 2, '2016-11-01 23:30:00' );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 2, '2016-12-01 23:30:00' );

insert into FlightPlan ( Name, FlightId ) values ( 'Phoenix to San Fran', 3 );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 3, '2016-09-01 07:30:00' );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 3, '2016-09-02 07:30:00' );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 3, '2016-09-03 07:30:00' );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 3, '2016-09-04 07:30:00' );

insert into FlightPlan ( Name, FlightId ) values ( 'San Fran to Phoenix',4 );
insert into FlightDate( FlightId, FlightDate ) values ( 4, '2016-09-05 07:30:00' );

-- Issue 1
select * 
from FlightPlan fp
join FlightDate fd
  on fp.FlightId = fd.FlightId
where FlightDate between '2016-09-01' and '2016-09-02'
order by fp.FlightId, FlightDate;

-- Issue 2
select * 
from FlightPlan fp
join FlightDate fd
  on fp.FlightId = fd.FlightId
where fp.FlightId = 1
order by fd.FlightDate asc;

-- Issue 2 alternate
select * from FlightPlan fp where fp.FlightId = 1;
select * from FlightDate fd where fd.FlightId = 1 order by FlightDate asc;
```

Comment: thanks for your complet answer, but i have more problems with issue#2 , users normaly search flights by callsign,and it return more than one flightplan ID, and show the result in gridview, by choosing each one form fill whit that flight to edit (so in search i will receive many flights ID that each one has many date of flight ), 
but two loop query make program Heavy load to first find flight ID's and then find dates for that ID .

Comment: i understand that i was wrong about array, but what if make my table much bigger (now has 16 column , add 30 column for each possible date) in this case i can search for date or callsign or flight ID, but i afraid of size of the table 
Or another way without need of loop query

Comment: You'll have many issues with 30 columns of dates, not just table size.    Maintaining the dates will be difficult.   Much easier to delete expired dates and insert new dates in a table like FlightDates than it is to figure out which column is empty, then update that column to null or a new date.   I recommend you read a little more into data modeling with SQL.